# How to bring custom block theme suggestions into the right hierachy?

Tags: blocks, 8, theming

I have to create theme suggestions for my content block types (custom blocks - configured via admin/structure/block/block-content/types), because i didn't find them as default suggestions.

The default was:

```
FILE NAME SUGGESTIONS:
* block--registernowheaderblock.html.twig
* block--block-content--7bd0dc95-f2ee-4e70-8a5a-90d718384712.html.twig
x block--block-content.html.twig
x block--block-content.html.twig
* block.html.twig
```

block--block-content.html.twig is not enough, because i need different custom block type templates. (Btw. 2 times block--block-content.html.twig?)

I need:

```
FILE NAME SUGGESTIONS:
x block--block-content--header-content-block.html.twig
* ...
* block.html.twig
```

So i tried in the theme file:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_theme_suggestions_HOOK_alter().
 */

function MYTHEME_theme_suggestions_block_alter(array &$suggestions, array $variables) 
{
    $block = $variables['elements'];
    $blockType = $block['#configuration']['provider'];
    if ($blockType == "block_content") {
        $bundle = $block['content']['#block_content']->bundle();
        $suggestions[] = 'block__' . $blockType . '__' . $bundle;
    }
}
```

This brings up:

```
FILE NAME SUGGESTIONS:
x block--block-content--header-content-block.html.twig
* block--registernowheaderblock.html.twig
* block--block-content--7bd0dc95-f2ee-4e70-8a5a-90d718384712.html.twig
* block--block-content.html.twig
* block--block-content.html.twig
* block.html.twig
```

Nice - but my suggestion is higher then the id based ones for single blocks - not good ... so i added

```
/**
 * Implements hook_theme_suggestions_HOOK_alter().
 */
function oeb_theme_suggestions_block_alter(array &$suggestions, array $variables) 
{
    $block = $variables['elements'];
    $blockType = $block['#configuration']['provider'];
    if ($blockType == "block_content") {
        $bundle = $block['content']['#block_content']->bundle();
        $blockUuid = $block['content']['#block_content']->uuid();
        $blockId = $block['#id'];
        $suggestions[] = 'block__' . $blockType . '__' . $bundle;
        $suggestions[] = 'block__' . $blockType . '__' . $bundle . '__' . $blockId;
        $suggestions[] = 'block__' . $blockType . '__' . $bundle . '__' . $blockUuid;
    }
}
```

Result

```
FILE NAME SUGGESTIONS:
* block--block-content--header-content-block--7bd0dc95-f2ee-4e70-8a5a-90d718384712.html.twig
* block--block-content--header-content-block--registernowheaderblock.html.twig
x block--block-content--header-content-block.html.twig
* block--registernowheaderblock.html.twig
* block--block-content--7bd0dc95-f2ee-4e70-8a5a-90d718384712.html.twig
* block--block-content.html.twig
* block--block-content.html.twig
* block.html.twig
```

This is not nice, because of the doubled id stuff - is it possible to get something like:

```
FILE NAME SUGGESTIONS:
* block--registernowheaderblock.html.twig
* block--block-content--7bd0dc95-f2ee-4e70-8a5a-90d718384712.html.twig
x block--block-content--header-content-block.html.twig
* block--block-content.html.twig
* block.html.twig
```

Means: Single blocks are the highest - but unique? Or should i live with this to keep the stuff simple?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you need is simple array manipulation. Basically split of the original suggestions add the the suggestions and merge the suggestions again.

Some like this should work (untested).

```
function oeb_theme_suggestions_block_alter(array &$suggestions, array $variables) {
  ...
  $first_sugestions = array_slice($suggestions, 0, 2); 
  $last_sugestions = array_slice($suggestions, 0, 2);
  $first_sugestions[] = 'block__' . $blockType . '__' . $bundle;
  $suggestion = array_merge($first_suggestions, $last_suggestions);
}
```

Comment: This is the correct answer.

Comment: This did not work for me, Drupal 10. Also a couple of typos.

Answer (score 7):

I add this hook in MYTHEME.theme:

```
function MYTHEME_theme_suggestions_block_alter(array &$suggestions, array $variables) {
  $block = $variables['elements'];
  $blockType = $block['#configuration']['provider'];
  if ($blockType == "block_content") {
    $bundle = $block['content']['#block_content']->bundle();
    array_splice($suggestions, 2, 0, 'block__' . $bundle);
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes this worked for me Drupal 10.